# Unicode sri character in tamil

Tags: fonts, fontforge

I'm developing on a custom font using FontForge software but I'm stuck with just one character for almost a month now. Sri (ஸ்ரீ) character is composed of these four characters: uni0BB8(ஸ) uni0BCD(்) uni0BB0(ர) uni0BC0(ீ). When I generate the font and test it with a word document, it appears as ஸ் ரீ instead of Sri (ஸ்ரீ) character. Can someone please help? Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: I also struck with same [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39525292/tamil-character-segmentation-using-java)

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is an entry in the ligatures table. See [instructions here](https://fontforge.github.io/editexample4.html#ligature)